# Layout of my Alpha Animation File

Tags: android

First of all Im trying to animate a TextView view in one of my app's but it doesn't seem to work. I believe the answer lies in the alpha.xml file; I keep getting an error from this file but can't determine why:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:duration="3000">
</alpha>
```

Also I later want to animate an entire activity before it appears. This screen will simply be the splash/load screen an should animate on over a period of time.

Any ideas?
Cheers

The java code which uses it goes like this:

```
private void RunAnimations() 
        {
        Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation ( this, R.anim.alpha );
        a.reset();

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.welcomeMessage );
        tv.clearAnimation();
        tv.startAnimation( a );
    }
```

The error in the XML file is:

Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Element type "alpha" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/

> ".
>       - error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)

:/

Comment: That part looks good. Show the java code where you are starting the animation from, perhaps the error is coming from there?

Comment: Yup, nothing wrong with that animation.

Comment: Animation XML looks fine

Comment: It'd help if you'd post the error.

Comment: The error in the XML file was: Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - Element type "alpha" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/
  >".
 - error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)

Answer (score 0):

I sorted it out - for some reason I had to use the set.xml and then add alpha to it in order for it to work